# Stack images one on top of another

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap with the grid system elements are automatically arranged side by side but is there a way to stack elements one on top of another?

I'm trying to create a photo gallery where i'm displaying 4 images,hiding them and triggering each photo with an assigned button.

But because these images are first arranged side by side,every time I show one image and hide the other the frame is being shifted.

Example:
So if the first image starts at point A the last image ends at point D.

Here is the code that I am using

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<script>

   $("#gallerytrigger_1").on('click',function(){
   $("#gallery_1").toggle();
   $("#gallery_2").hide(); 
   $("#gallery_3").hide();
   $("#gallery_4").hide();
});

$("#gallerytrigger_2").on('click',function(){
   $("#gallery_4").hide();
   $("#gallery_3").hide();  
   $("#gallery_2").toggle(); 
   $("#gallery_1").hide();
});

$("#gallerytrigger_3").on('click',function(){
   $("#gallery_4").hide(); 
   $("#gallery_3").toggle();
   $("#gallery_2").hide(); 
   $("#gallery_1").hide(); 
});

$("#gallerytrigger_4").on('click',function(){
   $("#gallery_4").toggle();
   $("#gallery_3").hide(); 
   $("#gallery_2").hide(); 
   $("#gallery_1").hide(); 
});
</script

@foreach($gallerys as $gallery)
<div class="col-sm-2">
 <br>
  <div id="gallery_{{$loop->iteration}}" style="display:none;">
   <p style="text-align: center;"><img style="width: 100%;border-radius: 
     6px;" src="/gallery/{{ $gallery->imagelocation }}"></p>
  </div>
 </div>
@endforeach

@foreach($gallerys as $gallery)
<div class="col-xs-2">
 <br>
  <div id="gallerytrigger_{{$loop->iteration}}">
   <hr>
   <img style="width: 200%;border-radius: 6px;margin-left: -12px;margin- 
    top: -100px;" src="/gallery/{{ $gallery->imagelocation }}">
  </div>    
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<script>
  $(".galleryTrigger").click(function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $(".gallery").hide();
      $("#gallery_"+id).show();
  });
</script>

@foreach($gallerys as $gallery)
<div class="col-sm-2">
 <br>
  <div id="gallery_{{$loop->iteration}}" style="display:none;" class="gallery">
   <p style="text-align: center;"><img style="width: 100%;border-radius: 
     6px;" src="/gallery/{{ $gallery->imagelocation }}"></p>
  </div>
 </div>
@endforeach

@foreach($gallerys as $gallery)
<div class="col-xs-2">
 <br>
  <div id="gallerytrigger_{{$loop->iteration}}" data-id="{{$loop->iteration}}" class="galleryTrigger">
   <hr>
   <img style="width: 200%;border-radius: 6px;margin-left: -12px;margin- 
    top: -100px;" src="/gallery/{{ $gallery->imagelocation }}">
  </div>    
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for simplifying the JQuery